# Аргумент по умолчанию для rvalue ссылки

Tags: c++, c++11

Можно ли задать аргумент по умолчанию для rvalue ссылки, например, так:

```
MyType f(double x, MyType && y = MyType()) {}
```

Компилятор сообщает, что так это функция одного аргумента.

Comment: Можно. "...что так это функция одного аргумента"  - что такое "это" и где вам компилятор такое сообщает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто функция имеет два аргумента и должна возвращать  `MyType`, но при этом она ничего не делает, не используются аргументы и ничего не возвращается( пустое тело функции).
Напишите или только обьявление:

```
MyType f(double x, MyType && y = MyType());
```

или  тело функции не оставляйте пустым